# Estimate minimum detectable light pulse in a photodiode (5 ms, 44 kHz modulated)?

Tags: noise, photodiode, pulse, signal-to-noise

I'll use an IR LED modulated at 44 kHz to illuminate particles in air or water, and will use a silicon photodiode to detect weak pulses of scattered light as they pass through the LED's collimated beam.

Photodiode is shielded from direct light, so it will exhibit only dark current except for say roughly 5 ms pulses, when light scattered by the particle illuminates the detector.

An example of a detector's specs are shown below, it needs to be a large area detector for geometrical reasons.

I'm trying to make a ballpark estimate of how weak of a pulse I can reliably detect without getting a lot of false positives from noise.

I'll amplify the signal then use a simple diode + bandpass filter (say 100 Hz to 1 kHz) to remove the 44 kHz but pass the envelope of the 5 ms pulses.

With a bandwidth of ~1 kHz, detectors dark current of 200 pA means every 5 milliseconds there will be about 6 million electrons, with an RMS (shot noise) of about 2500 e-. So if my 5 ms light pulses produce say 10,000 or 20,000 e-h pairs and I set a threshold there, I'm in the right ballpark.

The 0.55 A/W at 850nm means each photon has about an 80% chance of making an e-h pair.

However, I haven't used the capacitance of the photodiode at all, nor the NEP (1.5E-14 W/Hz^1/2 @ 1550 nm) which curiously is specified at a wavelength for which silicon is blind. In other words, I haven't designed an amplifier and threshold discriminator yet.

Is disaster waiting for me around the bend, or is this likely to work with a reasonable low nose amplifier and bandpass filter?

---

Some spec data for an example 10x10mm PIN photodiode: https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=FDS10X10

[image: Thorlabs 10x10mm PIN photodiode]

Comment: If you're doing anything at this low a light level, you might want to look into a photomultiplier instead of a photodiode.

Comment: A phototransistor may be a cheaper option, too, but they are slower to operate than photomultipliers or photodiodes. This may be acceptable to you; 5ms is probably long enough to activate a phototransistor.

Comment: My version of this datasheet says the NEP was measured at 960 nm (ie the peak sensitivity)

Comment: Use a lens to increase the solid angle of light scattered from the particles. You can then use a smaller, less expensive photodiode.

Comment: Simply put, unless you specify the particle density in the suspension, there is no possible way to answer the question. Once you do that, you then need to specify both the particle reflectance and the optical setup you've got. And, just out of curiosity, are attempting to detect single particles?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast This question is only about electronic noise in detection. I can adjust particle size or LED brightness or distances (in reality, and in simulation) in order to produce the desired pulse height in the photodetector. I'm only asking how to determine *what that desired pulse height might be.* In other words, how many e-h pairs to make in 5 ms to be well above false positives due to noise. re single particles, yes, that's what the pulses are.